# Unable to get current location on iOS version 11.2.6 xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c

Throwing following error when trying to get current location on iOS version 11.2.6 but works on versions < 11.

CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/386576ED-732A-4DBD-9E94-AD005A83021A/App.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileVersionID.omo'

Comment: where are you running your app? simulator or device?

Comment: on device iphone 6s

Comment: i was check but all ok in my project

Comment: try to clear your derived data.

Comment: how can i check duplicate core data

Answer (score 0):

Just update your `Podfile`

```
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
```

Also try a clean build! Try-

1. `cmd + k`
2. `cmd + alt + cmd + k`
3. `cmd + shift + B`

Comment: not working Still same error CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/257BDA41-4AA7-4E43-B975-6B6B0B4FD20B/App4Cab.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileVersionID.omo'

Comment: Did u update your pods? did u check when you run ur app your api gets a request?

Comment: yes i was update my pods and code running on ipad version 10.3.3 but ios 11 nor support

Comment: Your api getting any request???? Tell me on thing - did u restrict your place api for only iOS or left it open.And did u set   Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description? ..in your info.plish

Comment: Application restrictions "None" api restrictions "None" and yes i was set Location When In Use Usage Description in info.plist

Comment: need to see your full code

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine with ios < 11

```
import GoogleMaps
```

define delegate `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    return true
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let objLAt = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude
    let objLong = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude

    print(objLAt)
    print(objLong)
}
```

Comment: i was do all the things bro but its not work